# Send crash reports log file in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to allow user to send Email of application crash logs file. The problem is that from my device i am able to send logs file as an attachment of Email. But from some devices i am receiving Email but that don't have the attached logs file.
I am using following code to send Email logs file.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailer setSubject:@"Application Logs File"];

        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"my Email ID", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[Utility getCurrentLogsFileNameFromUserDefaults]];
        NSString* theFileName = [[Utility getCurrentLogsFileNameFromUserDefaults] lastPathComponent];
        NSLog(@"File Data %@",theFileName);

        [mailer addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/x-log" fileName:theFileName];

        NSString *emailBody = @"PFA for logs file.";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: What there in function `getCurrentLogsFileNameFromUserDefaults` ?

Comment: It will get the logs file name which i am storing in user defaults.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [Utility getCurrentLogsFileNameFromUserDefaults]); This should send you a filepath, and then check whether, actually any file is there on such path.

Comment: I can test that on my device. But how to check on other devices?.

Comment: For other device you should check if the file you are going to send is present on device then send it, otherwise send an email that the file is not there. May be the crash log did not write there or you are storing a wrong filename in UserDefaults.

Comment: @NeverHopeless They can see the file attached to mail composer on their iPhone. If they can see I think mail should have attachment.

Comment: Debug your code on device, and NSLog the filepath. Then get string data from file path and NSLog that string data.